# CakePHP session data cleared on paginator sort

Tags: session, cakephp, input, pagination

My session data is being saved in my form as expected.

However, when I run a sort on any column of my results, my form session values are cleared.

I am calling in my search form through en element as it's used on specific locations of the site.

Does anyone know why pagination is clearing out my session? Is this standard Cake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this:
[CakePHP session ID path or other method to share the results of a url - recommendations welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628076/cakephp-session-id-path-or-other-method-to-share-the-results-of-a-url-recommend)

Answer (score 0):

The paginator sort elements are simply a link generated by the paginator and won't consider any of your form data.  The first thing you need to make sure that you're doing is tell the paginator to include any URL paramters for the current page in the url it generates. Put this anywhere in the view before you call any of the $paginator functions.

```
$paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

Secondly, make sure that your search parameters are being included in the URL.  It sounds like they probably aren't.  I just answered another question on the best practices of search result URLs here:  [CakePHP Search Results Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628076/cakephp-session-id-path-or-other-method-to-share-the-results-of-a-url-recommend/)