# CakePHP session ID path or other method to share the results of a url - recommendations welcome

Tags: php, session, url, cakephp

I am looking for suggestions on a sensible Cake approach to creating a session id based url that I can share with others to see the same search results I am seeing on my end.

I know in standard php, I would just get the session id and pass it to the url. But my guess Cake probably has a method or approach for this exact thing (my guess). I have not been able to locate anything specific yet.

Any ideas as to the best approach to this with Cake methods? Or will I need to re-invent the wheel on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this:

```
search ( ... ) {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
        $this->Session->write('search_form_sess', $this->data);
        $initial_url = $ApplicantAge . '/' . $SpouseAge . '/' . $NumberChildren . '/' . $Vision . '/' . $Zip;
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'search', $initial_url));
        exit();
    }
...
```

}

Comment: Just curious, why doyou want the session values in the URL? Tyler's approach is the most commonly used method

Comment: #JohnP. I am storing the session values to retain the search form field data, so the user does not need to keep re-entering different search criteria, and can just change what needs to be changed as the search is refined.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking this because you are using POST and consequentially the URL does not include the search parameters, as it would through GET?

I use the following design paradigm for search on all the apps I build.

1. Search form submits as a POST.
2. In the controller action, if the form is submitted as a post, I extract the search parameters, and then redirect to a URL that includes the (named*) parameters.

So the action code might look something like this:

```
function search() {
    if($this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
        // let's say we extract parameters called $a and $b here
        $this->redirect(array(
            'action' => 'search',
            'a' => $a,
            'b' => $b
        )
        exit();
    )
    // perform the normal search operation
    // the 'a' and 'b' parameters can be accessed in the $this->params['named']
    // array, automatically extracted by the CakePHP router using the configuration below.
}
```

With regard to named parameters, I would have this set up in my routes.php:

```
Router::connectNamed(array('a', 'b'));
```

This results in the redirect above creating a nice, clean-looking URL like:

```
http://example.com/controller/search/a:FOO/b:BAR
```

Comment: This is called the Post : Redirect : Get pattern. For a good component that handles this for you look at the CakeDC plugin for filters. There is a base package called Utils (I believe) that has a PrgComponent you can use.

Comment: #Tyler. Thanks for your suggestion. I currently have my initial search url now reading like: ...plans/search/age:50/spouse:0/children:0/vision:0/zip:92258 BUT I cannot get rid of the prefixes on the values.. Router::connect(
 '/plan/:ApplicantAge:SpouseAge:NumberChildren:Vision:Zip',
  array('controller' => 'plan', 'action' => 'search'),
  array('pass' => array('ApplicantAge','SpouseAge','NumberChildren','Vision','Zip'))
 );

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by prefixes. Are you referring to age, spouse, etc?  You want the url to be /search/50/0/9/0/92258?