# Cakephp store session vars in session id to share url between users

Tags: session, url, cakephp

My script is working perfect as it stands, but I have been trying to resolve a way to pass session values (to maintain the form search criteria values) between two browsers on different machines (for sharing the query results).

I am looking at two approaches:

1) Extract the url parameters from the search string url path eg: ...url/50/1/4/5/98764 and echo them back out in the values of the search form.

2) Use a session (which I am using now to maintain the values) for an independent user. And this is working fine for a single browser of course.

My main question is what approach is best to share search results while maintaining the search values in the form fields?

YES. I am aware it's a bad idea to share session info like this, but its required I have no choice!

Comment: Having helped you in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628076/cakephp-session-id-path-or-other-method-to-share-the-results-of-a-url-recommend), I can't for the life of me understand why you're still trying to share session information.  Sessions are not meant to be shared.  Parameters are user-agnostic. Use the named parameters solution described in my answer to the above question.

Comment: Tyler, if you would have read my entire post above you would know I am not doing this of my choosing! I am using named paramters as it stands. I need to extract the params from the url to pass them to a session and display them in the form.

Comment: Sorry, I did misread your question. My apologies. Answer coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be #1, extract the parameters from the url and display them on the form.  You can keep it pretty clean by keeping the parameters for the url and form the same. I use a whitelist to extract and push to the view:

```
function search() {
    if(isset($this->data)) {
        // redirect to search with named params
        ...
    } else {
        $whitelist = array('param1','param2','param3');
        foreach($whitelist as $param) {
            if(isset($this->params['named'][$param])) {
                $this->data['Model'][$param] = $this->params['named'][$param];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you have your form something like:

```
echo $form->input('param1'),
     $form->input('param2'),
     $form->input('param3')
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for the information. And no worries on the earlier post. I would be frustrated too had I answered the same question over and over to the same person! But I think your solution above would be for naming the actual form fields??? I am looking to fill the form values with extracted url data not change the form input names. For example, the zip code field would remain all the same but the value (in the input options) would echo out like value="98756" (extracted from the url path).. Did I misread your reply?

Comment: In your controller action, if you load the data into $this->data. and assuming that the index names align, the formhelper will automatically use that data to populate the form.  For example, in your controller you do `$this->data['Model']['param1'] = 'test';` and then on your form you have `echo $form->input('Model.param1')`, the field will be automatically populated.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thanks for the clarification.